# How to test url of new tab after clicking a link in laravel dusk

Tags: laravel-dusk

I'm testing my website using Laravel Dusk and I want to test a link that open a new tab to check if it goes to the correct URL. My test looks like this;

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
     $browser->loginAs(User::find(1))
        ->visit('/test')
        ->waitForLocation('/test')
        ->click('#test-link');
     $window = collect($browser->driver->getWindowHandles())->last();
     $browser->driver->switchTo()->window($window);
     $url = $browser->driver->getCurrentURL();
     Assert::assertTrue($url == 'http://foobar.com');
});
```

The problem here is that the URL that I'm getting is just `about:blank`. At first, I thought it's because the new tab is still loading but I tried to add a `pause(5000)` before getting current URL but it still returns `about:blank`. Why does the new tab doesn't proceed with the URL of the link?

Answer (score 0):

did you try using `$browser->assertUrlIs("http://foobar.com");`